# How to mock a pika connection for a different module?

Tags: python, mocking, rabbitmq, python-unittest, pika

I have a class that imports the following module:

```
import pika
import pickle
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import time
import logging
class RabbitMQ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host="localhost"))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.sched = BackgroundScheduler()
        self.sched.add_job(self.keep_connection_alive, id='clean_old_data', trigger='cron', hour = '*', minute='*', second='*/50')
        self.sched.start()
    def publish_message(self, message , path="path"):
        message["path"] = path
        logging.info(message)
        message = pickle.dumps(message)
        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange="", routing_key="server", body=message)
    def keep_connection_alive(self):
        self.connection.process_data_events()
rabbitMQ = RabbitMQ()
def publish_message(message , path="path"):
    rabbitMQ.publish_message(message, path=path)
```

My class.py:

```
import RabbitMQ as rq
class MyClass():
...
```

When generating unit tests for MyClass I can't mock the connection for this part of the code. And keeping throwing exceptions. And it will not work at all

```
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5672 failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I tried a couple of approaches to mock this connection but none of those seem to work. I was wondering what can I do to support this sort of test? Mock the entire RabbitMQ module? Or maybe mock only the connection

Comment: The issue is the global `rabbitMQ` variable which will be initialized the moment this module is imported by another module or test. That means that a  `RabbitMQ` instance will be created before you have a chance to patch the connection. Are you able to move the `rabbitMQ = RabbitMQ()` line elsewhere?

Comment: I think I will have to do that. I didn't have a complete understanding of the `unittests` module and I was trying to mock before importing, which clearly hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the commenter above mentions, the issue is your global creation of your `RabbitMQ`.

My knee-jerk reaction is to say "just get rid of that, and your module-level `publish_message`". If you can do that, go for that solution. You have a `publish_message` on your `RabbitMQ` class that accepts the same args; any caller would then be expected to create an instance of your `RabbitMQ` class.

If you don't *want* to or *can't* do that for whatever reason, you should just move the instantiation of move that object instantiation in your module-level `publish_message` like this:

```
def publish_message(message , path="path"):
    rabbitMQ = RabbitMQ()
    rabbitMQ.publish_message(message, path=path)
```

This will create a new connection every time you call it though. Maybe that's ok...but maybe it's not. So to avoid creating duplicate connections, you'd want to introduce something like a singleton pattern:

```
class RabbitMQ():
    __instance = None

    ...

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls):
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = RabbitMQ()
        return cls.__instance

def publish_message(message , path="path"):
    RabbitMQ.get_instance().publish_message(message, path=path)
```

Ideally though, you'd want to avoid the singleton pattern entirely. Whatever caller should store a single instance of your `RabbitMQ` object and call `publish_message` on it directly.

So the TLDR/ideal solution IMO: Just get rid of those last 3 lines. The caller should create a `RabbitMQ` object.

EDIT: Oh, and the *why* it's happening -- When you import that module, this is being evaluated: `rabbitMQ = RabbitMQ()`. Your attempt to mock it is happening after that is evaluated, and fails to connect.

Comment: I will refactor the way this connection is done, that's what I think is causing the issue.